# Linear algebra behind principle stress orientations of mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics, computational-mathematics

Here is an example for 2x2 matrix (2D stress),
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{xx} &\sigma_{xy}\\
\sigma_{yx} &\sigma_{yy}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to be more specific,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
50 &30\\
30 &-20
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the principal orientation is
$$
\tan(2 \theta)=\frac{2\cdot30}{50-(-20)}\implies\theta=20.3^{\circ}
$$
The reference for this is section of 2-D Principal Stress Example of
https://www.continuummechanics.org/principalstressesandstrains.html

I was told that you can also get the $\theta$ if you calculate the eigenvector of this 2x2 matrix.
so I use MATLAB and get a two eigenvector of this matrix namely
$$
V_1=\begin{bmatrix}
0.3469 \\
-0.9379 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
V_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-0.9379 \\
-0.3469 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Anyone can tell me how to get this $20.3^\circ$ from the two eigenvectors?

Comment: Edited answer..

Comment: One feature to watch out for on the linked page: When the eigenvalue/eigenvector calculator reports eigenvectors, these are listed as *rows* not as *columns*. (This initially led me to think you still had a lingering sign error on your eigenvectors, but I think they're correct as you've written them.)

Comment: I edited the last three sentences. The eigenvector IS the rotation axis.

Comment: Take an xy plane. Plot the x and y values and you have a triangle where you know how long the sides are. Also when you draw the eigenvectors remember the opposite of it counts too, so let it pass through the origin the other direction. The same distance from the origin. Do this with both. Then ask about signs and stuff. I think that will help

Answer (score 1):

To explain what's going on here, I'll first focus on the numerical eigenvectors. Note that, as is common with numerical eigenvectors, $V_1$ is normalized to have length 1 (within numerical precision):

$$\|V_1\|^2 =V_1^t  V_1=V_{1x}^2+V_{1y}^2=0.3469^2+(-0.9379)^2=1$$

What's convenient about this is that *any* such normalized 2D vector is of the form $[\cos\theta,\sin\theta]^t$. Geometrically, $\theta$ is simply the angle that the eigenvector makes with the positive $x$-axis. Applying this to $V_1$ and $V_2$, we seemingly have
$$\theta_1 =\cos^{-1}(0.3469)=69.7^\circ,\qquad \theta_2=\cos^{-1}(-0.9379)=159.7 ^\circ.$$
However, these values are misleading: by definition, the inverse cosine function only returns angles in the range $0$ to $180^\circ$. But any angle in this range will have a positive sine, which is incorrect for both. As such, both angles should differ by a minus sign: $\theta_1=-69.7^\circ, \theta_2=-159.7^\circ$.

This still doesn't give the desired orientation angle. What we need to realize at this point is that eigenvectors are always ambiguous in the following sense: If $V$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is any constant multiple of $V$. In particular, $-V$ is also an eigenvector with this eigenvalue. So we also need to consider the angles corresponding to $-V_1,-V_2$. But this amounts to shifting the two angles by $180^\circ$. If we add $180^\circ$ to both angles, we get $110.3^\circ$ for $-V_1$ and $20.3^\circ$ for $-V_2$. So at last we have the desired orientation angle. (The only last check is that the second eigenvector corresponds to the larger stress, and I assume you've already done this.)

Thus far I've focused on the numerical eigenvectors. But the OP also noted that the principal orientation can be calculated directly from the matrix. To see how this proceeds, suppose the strain matrix has an eigenvector $V=[\cos\theta,\sin\theta]^t$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. For this to be true, we need

$$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy}\\ \sigma_{yx} & \sigma_{yy}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}.$$ This amounts to a system of two equations, and we may solve both for the principal stress as

$$\lambda = \sigma_{xx}+\sigma_{xy}\tan\theta = \sigma_{yy}+\sigma_{yx}\cot\theta$$
To proceed further, note that $\sigma_{yx}=\sigma_{xy}$ since the strain matrix is symmetric. Hence we may rearrange this equation as
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma_{xx}-\sigma_{yy}}{\sigma_{xy }}
&=\cot\theta-\tan\theta\\
&=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}\\
&=\frac{2\cos(2\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)}\\
&=2 \cot(2\theta)
\end{align}

Therefore $\tan(2\theta)=\dfrac{2\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_{xx}-\sigma_{yy}}$ which is exactly the computation applied in the OP.

Comment: Some of the complications in the above work, it should be noted, could be avoided by making a sketch of the two eigenvectors first. In that case, it would have been clear that the relevant angle is that produced by $-V_2$ rather than $V_2$. But I wanted to show how to deal with these issues at the level of algebra alone.

Comment: Did get where this -0.3445 come from

Comment: @majordoctor It's a holdover from the original values you had. Fixed.

Comment: Thats good thank you. 

Comment: The eigenvalues for this matrix are -31.1 and 61.1. So does $110.3^\circ$(I guess you have a small typo) is pair with -31.1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that the two axes are 90 degrees apart, as it must be for a symmetric strain matrix. (There's some subtleties that emerge when principal stresses coincide, particularly in the 3D case. But one can always pick the eigenvectors so as to be orthogonal.) @majordoctor

Comment: For this add $180^\circ$, can I always add it?

Comment: Not really. The eigenvectors you chose lay in the third and fourth quadrants respectively, and thus necessitated the adjustments I made. Had you written the second eigenvector as $V_2=[0.9379,0.3469]^t$, then it would have been acceptable to simply take $\cos^{-1}(0.9379)=20.3^\circ$ directly. So it's probably best to draw the eigenvectors to begin with and deduce the appropriate angle geometrically.

Comment: So maybe only the negative angle needs to add 180, and positive doesn't change?

Comment: Possibly. But it seems best to use geometric intution to decide such questions. There is one point of ambiguity. For instance, suppose the principal axis of larger stress is the line $y=-x$ through the origin. Is this reported as an orientation of $135^\circ$ or $-45^\circ$? If we _define_ $\theta=\frac12 \tan^{-1}[2\sigma_{xy}/(\sigma_{xx}-\sigma_{yy})]$, as per the first formula you applied, then $-45^\circ$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128557/discussion-between-majordoctor-and-semiclassical).

Comment: For the result we got from atan(V_y/V_x), the angel is to x-axis or y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

A rotation matrix has a vector that it is rotating things about, and an angle. The vector can be defined using its angle from the x-axis. That’s what $\theta$ is.

If we take any point that’s already *on* the axis of rotation then it will not be rotated. That is the same as an eigenvector. (Because the eigenvector of a matrix is the vector that when multiplied by the matrix gives the same vector direction - ie pointed in the same way, in this case not rotated.)

So the eigenvector *is* the axis.

Take the eigenvector where x and y have the same sign. In this case both negative. Then take the arc-cos (|the x part of the eigenvector|), or take the arc-sin (|the y part of the eigenvector|).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need eigenvalue.

Comment: what do you mean arcsin of y? I use arcsin(-0.9379), did't get 20.3. Already consider arc and angle

Comment: Ok that means the angle is being measured from the x axis and so it would be the arccos of y. Easiest thing to do while learning is take the sin and cos of your angle and see

Comment: I guess it makes sense to measure from the x axis. Sorry for the mixup

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get your point, can you show the solution procedure that you get this $20.3^\circ$

Comment: Theta = arc-cos (.9379). Or = arcsin (.3469)

Comment: Thank you, but what is the reason that we abandon the negative sign? Is this ok for any matrix?

Comment: Draw the eigenvectors on an xy plane. Use trig to get the angle from the x axis.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have questions need to consider eigenvalue, as your former answer, the eigenvalues are -31.1 and 61.1. In mechanics, they call the smallest one is the minimum principal stress, so for the minimum principal stress direction, how to decide which one to use among $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: The machine should tell you i think. Beyond that i dont know

Comment: I think there will be a case that no eigenvector has the same sign, then what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128548/discussion-between-al-brown-and-majordoctor).